# Installing .NET core 1.0.1 for Visual Studio Code without installing Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just reformatted my computer. I installed Visual Studio Code, but is prompting me to install CLI tools for debugging when loading a .NET project. Every time I run the .NET Core setup, it prompts me to install Visual Studio 2015. I don't want to install it as it takes up a lot of resources. I had Visual Studio Code working before without it. I only have Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.1 installed. What else do I need to do so I can install CLI tools for debugging without installing Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [.Net Core website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows); it does appear as though they require VS2015 (currently at update 3).

They have a note under the first list that speaks of being able to use the ".NET Core SDK for Windows" ([install link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827524)) alone with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). This may be the approach you desire.

*The above is for the Windows platform.* The other supported platforms are similar.

---

*A note on the general build tools.*

Microsoft provides packages intended for build servers etc. for [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/); they contain the tools typically required to just build the code. Look for the "Microsoft Build Tools 2015" under the "Tools for Visual Studio 2015" section of the downloads. [Direct link to the Web installer](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615458).

The collection above is described as;

> If you don’t already have Visual Studio installed on your computer, Microsoft Build Tools 2015 provides the essential tools for building managed applications. These tools previously were included in the .NET Framework, but they are now available as this separate download. The Visual Basic and C# compilers are also included in this download.

There are also the C++ tools available, but as a separate download.

Comment: It still wouldn't let me install .NET core after installing the build tools. Any other suggestions? I had this running before, but I forgot what dependencies I had installed that had it running flawlessly.

Comment: It looks like you may need the ".NET Core SDK for Windows" ([install link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827524)), I haven't tried this mix on Windows. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code provides a simple way to create the new core & other projects.

1. Navigate to visual studio code terminal ( press Ctrl + `)
2. You can create the new project, check list of available project templates using simple command `dotnet new` `-l`

as explained [by Microsoft Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd)  **[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x)**

[image]